# Java Key Binding Not Working

Tags: java

I have this code:

```
        frame = new JFrame();
    frame.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
            isRunning = false;
        }
    });
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setSize(width * scale, height * scale);
    frame.setResizable(false);
    frame.setVisible(true);

    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    frame.add(panel);
    panel.setFocusable(true);
    panel.requestFocusInWindow();

    // KeyBinds
    KeyManager.start(panel);
```

And in KeyManager:

```
    public static void start(JComponent comp) {
    comp.requestFocus();
    comp.requestFocusInWindow();

    comp.getInputMap(JComponent.WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW).put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_W, 0), "w");
    comp.getActionMap().put("w", new AbstractAction() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            pressedKeys.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("w"), true);
        }
    });
```

But my code only works sometimes. Is there a problem somewhere? Is there a line of code I need to add?

Comment: Can you be more specific about _how_ it's not working? What are you expecting to happen and what's happening instead?

Comment: Well, when I press "w", the hashmap that gets changed is not changed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I fixed the problem. I used a hashmap (Keystroke, Boolean) to store the key values. I read that using KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(String key) is not a good idea, so I changed the hashmap to using (Integer, Boolean) with the integer being KeyEvent.VK_(key). It works now :)